# Malwarebytes Tray Application appearing in Alt-Tab list

Tags: windows-10, alt-tab, malwarebytes

Recently, "Malwarebytes Tray Application" has been appearing in the list of open apps when I press Alt-Tab.  Selecting it does nothing.  If I double-click the Malwarebytes icon in the system tray, it opens separately, so that there is both the empty "Malwarebytes Tray Application" and the actual app.  Any idea of how to stop it from appearing?
This has happened on multiple PCs, mostly installed via Ninite.

Comment: Two Workarounds : [Malwarebytes Tray Application Appears in Alt + Tab Switching Window](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/malwarebytes-tray-app-alt-tab-switch-window-mbtray/)

Comment: Good find.  Feel free to describe both workarounds in an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a post on the Malwarebytes Forums, about a month ago in Sept 2017.  Apparently this behavior is by design.  Since I don't use their premium service, I stopped all notifications, which wasn't enough, and stopped it from starting when Windows started.  That was required to stop the phantom application from appearing in the Alt-Tab list.
https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/209606-322-tray-application-appearing-as-processalt-tab-window/